# vector.size() - 2 leads to infinite loop - C++

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

I am trying to run a loop on vector but not on the last two elements. So for that I used the following implementation:

```
vector<int> x;
for(int i=0;i<x.size()-2;i++){
    cout<<"looping over element"<<endl;
}
```

However, running the above code with no elements inserted into x leads to an infinite loop.
Ideone [link](http://%20https://ideone.com/r5Bh7p):

Why do I get this behavior? If `x.size()==0` then `i<-2` condition should not hold and the code should never enter the for loop

Comment: Did you actually try printing what `x.size()-2` is? You'll be surprised to learn that the result is not -2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x.size()` returns an unsigned value. If this is smaller than `2` then the value will underflow and the result will become very large.

On the other hand since `i` is a *signed* type hen it will sooner or later come to the max value of an `int` (which will still be less than the result of `x.size() - 2`), and then `i++` will lead to arithmetic overflow which is *undefined behavior*.

Before you attempt this loop you must make sure that `x.size() >= 2`, *and* you need to make sure that the counter variable is an unsigned type (like `size_t`):

```
if (x.size() >= 2)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size() - 2; ++i)
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When x.size() is smaller than 2, and you subtract two, you get some big value, as the result is unsigned, and ((someunsigned)-1) is a huge number
So the loop runs:

```
i=0
i=50000
i=1000000
i=4,294,967,295 //Stop
```

So, you have no infinite loop, only a very long running loop